# Azure IoT Hub SDK cross compile

Tags: cross-compiling, arm64, azure-iot-sdk

I want to cross compile Azure IoT Hub SDK for target `arm64` on my host which is `amd64`.

For this I need some libraries like `curl openssh`. I can't do it like Microsoft say on github, to use rsync to link folder from raspberry.

How I can get this libraries for target `arm64`? Do I have to download and build it from source?

Comment: Have a look at this documentation for quick glimpse on [Cross Compiling the Azure IoT Hub SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/main/doc/SDK_cross_compile_example.md)

Comment: I looked add this documentation but they used rsync. I don't have physically target board so this solution will be not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This example demonstrates how to build all of the dependencies and the IoT SDK in a Docker container. You could adapt it to run on the host if you wished. https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/main/doc/Docker_SDK_Cross_Compile.md